# How to Push Nested Json to Firebase (Server Side)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been experimenting with Fire-base from few days on Server side setup. Which I have done successfully.But I have a challenge in pushing Nested Json to Firebase.

Ex: Json Data from Mongo with some nested structure

```
{
    "displayName":"<RestaurantName>",
    "id":"<id>",
    "Menu": {
        "MenuName":"<MenuName>",
        "menuid":"<menuid>"
    }
}
```

Node.js code :

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

// Initialize the app with no authentication
firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "<url>"
});

// The app only has access to public data as defined in the Security Rules
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref();
var ordersRef = ref.child("orders");

ordersRef.push(data);
```

Here I can able pass the **restaurant Name and Id ** but the Nested Sub Node data which is `MenuName`, `menuId` data is not being pushed in to the object.

Could you give me any suggestion, please ?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting `data` from?

Comment: it is the api response from mongo  by nodejs server

Comment: and are you sure you are getting it correctly by the time u call `.push`? try loging the data right before the push to see if its comming as you expect. There is nothing wrong with the code you provided. And please add the result from the log to the question.

Comment: That Make sense. Actually we are doing api call With async parellel. the logged data has the values save in json . may be i need to give some seconds time gap before push

Comment: Hi Just one query . I see Undefined fields are not accepting by Firebase is there any way to let it accept ?

Comment: no, you cant set an object with `{ "data": undefined }`. This will pretty much depends on the reason why you are trying to do it. You could go with an empty string `{"data": ""}`

Comment: Yes that is a bad practice ofcourse but dynamic generating data may have some undefined which is not being allowed by Firebase . so trying to find some solution. Thankyou for the Answer adolforsrs :-)